# Place one instance of model in ARCore Sceneform

Tags: arcore, sceneform

Having completed the Sceneform quickstart, I'm still having trouble implementing my model placement method...

Rather than each touch of the screen placing a new instance of the model (as in the quickstart & codelab), I'm trying to have each touch reposition the model to that location while still retaining the drag & scale interation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...
Hi Mark,

you can try to save a reference to node that you have created previously at your first touch. I mean the TransformableNode that is used into the codelab.
When you touch on another point:

1- Detach that node from it's current parent.

2- Attach the node to the new Anchor you have just created on the hit.

Hope this help.

Cheers